AWS Lambda timing out when I try to initiatize the Lambda() function from 'aws-sdk'
I am trying to invoke another lambda function from one lambda. However, even before getting to the invoke() line, lambda is timing out after 10 seconds. Here is the code:
import { Lambda } from "aws-sdk";
var lambda = new Lambda({ region: 'us-east-1' }) //Timing out at this line even when I comment out the below lines

/*lambda.invoke( {
                FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:99999999999:function:myfunction',
                InvocationType: 'Event',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({ test: "message" })
            }).promise()*/


Why is it taking so long just to initialize the method? If the problem is with the IAM role execution, shouldn't the error be different ?

Have you tried updating the Lambda Timeout seconds?

The caller Lambda is actually an API and its timeout is set to 10 seconds.
